# Content Organizer creates wrong modified date (2013)

Tags: date-time, content-organizer, modified

We are using Content Organizer feature to route documents from one site collection to another. We have noticed that upon arriving to the destination documents library, each document has wrong modified date, it shows “5 hours ago”.

The process of routing takes a couple of seconds. The time zone setting are all the same on all site collections.  If you upload a document directly into that same library, the Modified date/time is right.

Comment: Does the web application have a time zone set?

Comment: Yup it's the same time zone as the site collection regional settings, as well as the server time with central admin on it. It's weird to see the modified date be 5 hrs before the created date.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Content Organizer as is or have you created a custom workflow that moves the documents?

I have a client that was having the same symptoms. We didn't find the root cause but when we stopped using the custom workflow he had built the problem went away.